# Is there a fool-proof way to keep up with inflation?

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, bonds, inflation, investment-strategies

I know I can keep cash in an interest-based bank account, but that type of investment will not keep up with inflation, it seems.

Would I be right to assume that government/corporate bonds can keep up with inflation? More importantly: does a safe investment exist which can at least keep up with inflation?

UK based.

Comment: @Chad I voted to close this one, but if it's closed, should I copy my answer to the other one, since none of the current answers talk about indexes that track inflation-indexed bonds, only the bonds themselves.

Comment: I would say that your answer is equally valid on the other question as well.

Comment: @JohnBensin - absolutely - that's the one issue with closing dups, sometime excellent answers were already posted.

Comment: @JohnBensin We can merge the answers from this question into the other if this question is an exact duplicate.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea That's fine with me. From what I can tell of the last question (the minimum investment question), that's a much smoother process than my copying my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, you could use an index fund or ETF that invests in instruments indexed to the [Consumer Price Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Price_Index_%28United_Kingdom%29). One option is the [iShares Barclays £ Index-Linked Gilts (INXG)](http://uk.ishares.com/en/rc/products/INXG), which

> is an exchange traded fund (ETF) that aims to track the performance of the Barclays World Government Inflation-Linked Bond Index as closely as possible.

You still need to take into account commissions, among other factors, and understand that any investment comes with risk. Note that this ETF *aims* to track the performance of an inflation-linked bond index. It may not succeed all the time. **This isn't a fool-proof strategy, unfortunately, because investing is always a trade-off between risk and return.** By excepting a higher return, i.e., one that can keep up with inflation, you do bear a higher level of risk.

[Vanguard.co.uk](https://www.vanguard.co.uk/documents/adv/literature/inflation-linked-bonds.pdf) has good general information about inflation-indexed instruments and funds too.

Comment: These are not really fool proof though they are probably as close as you can get.   Just like any investment fund there are risks.  Also while the CPI is a key metric for gauging inflation it is not the only metric and at least theoretically the CPI could lag significantly behind real inflation

Comment: @Chad I stated in my answer that "any investment comes with risk" but I'll make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The Government (through National Savings and Investments) issues index-linked savings certificates periodically. At the moment there are none for sale to new customers, but if you had held some previously, you can re-invest them in more index-linked bonds when they mature. You can also sign up [here](http://www.nsandi.com/savings-index-linked-savings-certificates) to get notified when a new issue comes on sale.